# Test en Spring Boot contra una base de datos real

Tags: java, mysql, api, spring-boot, rest

Tengo un problema, nunca he realizado tests (Cosas de junior con 2 meses de experiencia real).
El caso es que me han asignado una tarea que consiste en realizar test a una Api Rest hecha en Spring Boot contra una base de datos en MySql.
El problema está en que no sé como realizar las pruebas directamente sobre esa base de datos, sin tener que crear una base de datos en memoria, un repositorio, etc.

Si alguien sabe por dónde puedo tirar para encontrar la solución, se agradecería!

O si tenéis documentación específica que me oriente un poco lo agradecería también!

Muchas gracias :D

Comment: Hay varios niveles a los que podrías atacar para testear contra la base de datos. Podrías hacer tests a [nivel de API](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/) (ojo, sin mockear nada) o podrías hacer tests directamente en tu capa de acceso a datos. En todo caso no los veas como tests unitarios. Piensa en ellos más bien como si tu aplicación (o capa de acceso a datos) fueran una caja negra de la que sabes qué debería ocurrir si la llamas con un determinado input.

Comment: Hola! gracias por responder! Al final lo hice contra la capa de acceso a datos y he conseguido montar una bateria de test bastante completa! Muchas gracias :D